# excel if formula - more than one word

Tags: excel, if-statement

I want to read the column and see if it contains the word 'Carpet', it makes it so I want it to print "Vista" otherwise "blue"

I can do that with the following formula. But if Kkoolumnen innheåller two or more words so it will not work?

=OM(D5="Carpet";"Vista";"Blue")

Comment: Your formula does compare the entire string, it's not anything with "contains". Use `FIND`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("Carpet", D5), 0), "Vista", "Blue")
```

Your formula is checking if the left side is **equal** to the right side. If you use the search function you will check if a string contains another string. The search functions return "error" if the string doesn't contains the interesting patter so it is a good patter to use IFERROR before Search.